# registration form won't return true because of issue gender section

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, radio-button

The registration form (with validation) I created is almost finished, but there's a bit problem on the genders section of the form: Even when I checked one of radio buttons and the whole form is filled up, the form still won't return true. I need your help for this.

HTML

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="reg-form col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 fname_group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="reg_first_name" class="form-control reg_first_name" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="help-block fname_error hidden"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 lname_group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="reg_last_name" class="form-control reg_last_name" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="help-block lname_error hidden"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 email_group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="reg_email" class="form-control reg_email" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="help-block email_error hidden"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 uname_group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="reg_username" class="form-control reg_username" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="help-block uname_error hidden"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 pword_group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="reg_password" class="form-control reg_password">
        <span class="help-block pword_error hidden"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 pword_again_group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="reg_password_again" class="form-control reg_password_again">
        <span class="help-block pword_again_error hidden"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="radio col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 gender_group">
        <label><input type="radio" class="reg_radio_male" name="reg_gender" value="Male"> Male</label>
        <label><input type="radio" class="reg_radio_female" name="reg_gender" value="Female"> Female</label>
        <span class="help-block gender_error hidden"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default">
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
'use strict';

let $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

class Validate {
    is_blank(field) {
        return $(field).value.length == 0;
    }
    exactPattern(field, pattern) {
        return $(field).value.match(pattern);
    }
    lessThanLength(field, textlength) {
        return $(field).value.length < textlength;
    }
    moreThanLength(field, textlength) {
        return $(field).value.length > textlength;
    }
    falseMatch(firstfield, secondfield) {
        return $(firstfield).value != $(secondfield).value;
    }
}

class Errors {
    addClass(field, className) {
        return $(field).classList.add(className);
    }
    removeClass(field, className) {
        return $(field).classList.remove(className);
    }
    displayError(span, errorMessage) {
        return $(span).innerHTML = errorMessage;
    }
}

let val = new Validate();
let err = new Errors();

function fnameError() {
    if(val.is_blank('.reg_first_name')) {
        err.addClass('.fname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.fname_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.fname_error', 'hidden');
    } else if(val.lessThanLength('.reg_first_name', 2)) {
        err.addClass('.fname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.fname_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.fname_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.fname_error', 'Minimum: 2 characters');
    } else if(!val.exactPattern('.reg_first_name', /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)) {
        err.addClass('.fname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.fname_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.fname_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.fname_error', 'Enter a valid first name');
    } else {
        err.removeClass('.fname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.fname_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.fname_error', 'hidden');
    }
    return true;
}

function lnameError() {
    if(val.is_blank('.reg_last_name')) {
        err.addClass('.lname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.lname_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.lname_error', 'hidden');
    } else if(val.lessThanLength('.reg_last_name', 2)) {
        err.removeClass('.lname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.lname_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.lname_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.lname_error', 'Minimum: 2 characters');
    } else if(!val.exactPattern('.reg_last_name', /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)) {
        err.addClass('.lname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.lname_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.lname_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.lname_error', 'Enter a valid last name');
    } else {
        err.removeClass('.lname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.lname_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.lname_error', 'hidden');
    }
    return true;
}

function emailError() {
    if(val.is_blank('.reg_email')) {
        err.addClass('.email_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.email_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.email_error', 'hidden');
    } else if(!val.exactPattern('.reg_email', /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i)) {
        err.addClass('.email_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.email_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.email_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.email_error', 'Enter a valid email address');
    } else {
        err.removeClass('.email_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.email_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.email_error', 'hidden');
    }
    return true;
}

function unameError() {
    if(val.is_blank('.reg_username')) {
        err.addClass('.uname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.uname_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.uname_error', 'hidden');
    } else if(val.lessThanLength('.reg_username', 6)) {
        err.removeClass('.uname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.uname_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.uname_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.uname_error', 'Minimum: 6 characters');
    } else if(val.moreThanLength('.reg_username', 20)) {
        err.removeClass('.uname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.uname_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.uname_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.uname_error', 'Maximum: 20 characters');
    } else if(!val.exactPattern('.reg_username', /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/)) {
        err.addClass('.uname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.uname_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.uname_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.uname_error', 'Enter a valid username. No spaces');
    } else {
        err.removeClass('.uname_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.uname_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.uname_error', 'hidden');
    }
    return true;
}

function pwordError() {
    if(val.is_blank('.reg_password')) {
        err.addClass('.pword_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.pword_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.pword_error', 'hidden');
    } else if(val.lessThanLength('.reg_password', 8)) {
        err.removeClass('.pword_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.pword_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.pword_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.pword_error', 'Minimum: 8 characters');
    } else if(val.moreThanLength('.reg_password', 20)) {
        err.removeClass('.pword_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.pword_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.pword_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.pword_error', 'Maximum: 20 characters');
    } else if(!val.exactPattern('.reg_password', /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/)) {
        err.addClass('.pword_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.pword_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.pword_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.pword_error', 'Enter a valid password. No spaces');
    } else {
        err.removeClass('.pword_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.pword_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.pword_error', 'hidden');
    }
    return true;
}

function pwordAgainError() {
    if(val.is_blank('.reg_password_again')) {
        err.addClass('.pword_again_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.pword_again_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.pword_again_error', 'hidden');
    } else if(val.falseMatch('.reg_password_again', '.reg_password')) {
        err.removeClass('.pword_again_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.pword_again_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.pword_again_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.pword_again_error', 'Passwords do not match');
    } else {
        err.removeClass('.pword_again_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.pword_again_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.pword_again_error', 'hidden');
    }
    return true;
}

function genderError() {
    if(!$('.reg_radio_male').checked && !$('.reg_radio_female').checked) {
        err.removeClass('.gender_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.gender_error', 'hidden');
        err.addClass('.gender_error', 'show');
        err.displayError('.gender_error', 'Gender is required');
    } else {
        err.removeClass('.gender_group', 'has-error');
        err.removeClass('.gender_error', 'show');
        err.addClass('.gender_error', 'hidden');
    }
    return true;
}

$('.reg_first_name').onblur = fnameError;
$('.reg_last_name').onblur = lnameError;
$('.reg_email').onblur = emailError;
$('.reg_username').onblur = unameError;
$('.reg_password').onblur = pwordError;
$('.reg_password_again').onblur = pwordAgainError;

$('.reg-form').onsubmit = function() {
    if(fnameError() && lnameError() && emailError() && unameError() && pwordError() && pwordAgainError() && genderError()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

P.S: Sorry for too much class names because I'm using bootstrap for the design of the form.

Answer (score 0):

**First,** all your ..Error() functions return *true*, regardless of the result of the *if*-statements. You need them to return *false*, if no errors are found.
 **Second,** you are using *&&* (and) between the calls of the ..Error() functions. But you want, to get a *false* returned, even if only one error occurs. To achieve this, use the *||* (or) instead.

This should solve your difficulties.

*Note:* you can do it the other way round as well, so return *false*, if an error was found. Instead of changing the *&&* ands, you'd need to swap the *false* and the *true* in your *onsubmit* function.


Greets

Comment: So should I change the `return true` in my Error() functions to `return false`?

Comment: @JTrixx16 No, thats exactly the problem. Your Error functions will always return the same value, regardless of whether an error was found or not. Make them to return usually 'false' , for "no error found", but add 'return true;' to the *if* cases, which describe an error handling. Note however that a return will always end the function execution, so always place it last

Comment: So you mean for `if` and `else if` statements, they must have `return true`, and for `else` statements, `return false`?

Comment: Its hard to explain in comment section. Your Error functions job is to check for errors and in case adjust the classes so it displays properly, isn't it? If so, you need to make your Error function in case of an error to not only adjust the css, but return the opposite of the default value in the end. Did you write those functions on your own?

Comment: @JTrixx16 okay, so I took a look at your functions again. The simplest way will be, to always add a `return false;` at the bottom of the last `else` in each Error() function, as this is the block, which gets executed, if no errors were found. And dont forget, to change the `&&` in `||` inside the `onsubmit` function. I hope, this will do it. Greets!

Comment: What I did are:
- remove the default `return true` in every Error() functions.
- for every if and else if statement, I return true.
- for every else statement, I return false.
- on the submission of form, I changed the `&&` to `||`. `return false`, if there are any errors. `return true` if none.

Comment: @JTrixx16 Sounds like it is, what I ment. So try it out, if it works. If not, I can send you my version of it via some way.